# Trouble sending faucet SOL on devnet from one wallet to another

Tags: web3.js, transactions, wallet, transaction, send-transaction

I've attempted to send funds from one wallet to another. The wallet I intend to send from is credited with 5 SOL and the recipient wallet has 1 SOL. I run either `npx esrun transfer.ts 4UVALcW69V3XMeEVqnDqciv1y17kPEdsSmKodHiqf9nN` or `ts-node transfer.ts 4UVALcW69V3XMeEVqnDqciv1y17kPEdsSmKodHiqf9nN` yet I get these errors respectively,

```
PS C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair> npx esrun .\transfer.ts 4UVALcW69V3XMeEVqnDqciv1y17kPEdsSmKodHiqf9nN
node:internal/process/esm_loader:108
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\node_modules\.bin\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js' imported from C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\node_modules\.bin\esrun-1704630798378.tmp.mjs
Did you mean to import ../../@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js?
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:496:5)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:327:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:946:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1132:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.18.0
```

or

```
PS C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair> ts-node .\transfer.ts 4UVALcW69V3XMeEVqnDqciv1y17kPEdsSmKodHiqf9nN  
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
suppliedToPubkey: 4UVALcW69V3XMeEVqnDqciv1y17kPEdsSmKodHiqf9nN
✅ Loaded our own keypair, the destination public key, and connected to Solana
Error sending SOL: SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5922:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5881:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5869:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\utils\send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:35:21)
    at async sendSol (C:\Users\Student\Documents\Solana_Web3\generate-keypair\transfer.ts:46:27) {
  logs: []
}
```

This is my package.json file,

```
{
  "name": "generate-keypair",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "rebuild": "npm rebuild",
    "start": "npm start transfer.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@solana-developers/node-helpers": "^1.2.1",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.87.6",
    "bs58": "^5.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "esrun": "^3.2.26",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

This is my transfer.ts file,

```
    Connection,
    Transaction,
    SystemProgram,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
    PublicKey,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import "dotenv/config"
import { getKeypairFromEnvironment } from "@solana-developers/node-helpers";

async function sendSol() {

    try {

        const suppliedToPubkey = process.argv[2] || null;

        if (!suppliedToPubkey) {
            console.log(`Please provide a public key to send to`);
            process.exit(1);
        }

        const senderKeypair = getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY");

        console.log(`suppliedToPubkey: ${suppliedToPubkey}`);

        const toPubkey = new PublicKey(suppliedToPubkey);

        const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");

        console.log(
            `✅ Loaded our own keypair, the destination public key, and connected to Solana`
        );

        const transaction = new Transaction();

        const LAMPORTS_TO_SEND = 5000;

        const sendSolInstruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: senderKeypair.publicKey,
            toPubkey,
            lamports: LAMPORTS_TO_SEND,
        });

        transaction.add(sendSolInstruction);

        const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
            senderKeypair,
        ]);

        console.log(
            ` Finished! Sent ${LAMPORTS_TO_SEND} to the address ${toPubkey}. `
        );
        console.log(`Transaction signature is ${signature}!`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending SOL:", error);
    }
}

sendSol();
```

May I get some help on where I've gone wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Your first error refers to some dependency problem, so for the sake of simplicity I recommend doing it the way that produces the second error. There, the main problem is `Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.`. In other words, the account you're trying to send funds from doesn't have any money on it.

This could be for various reasons:

- Connected to the wrong network, you might have funds on your wallet on devnet, but you're connected to mainnet-beta/testnet
- Specifying the account in the wrong spot e.g. you might be passing the your recipient account as the sending account by accident

Case 2 doesn't seem to be problem from looking at your code, so double check your sending wallet has the SOL on the correct network (devnet in your case).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did make sure both wallets were on devnet and I am connected to the devnet. Furthermore, I've tried both public keys just to make sure that wasn't the issue but I get a similar response. Both of the wallets are credited, the sender wallet has 5 SOL and the recipient one has 1 SOL. 

Not really sure what to do to fix the issue.